# How to partition pandas data frame according to time stamp?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame columns Time Stamp,ID,Latitude,Longitude.  This data frame about one month period.  How do I plot number of distinct visited location VS time(per day or week)?

```
Time Stamp              Id  Latitude    Longitude
08/10/2016 15:22:51:700 1      23        50
08/10/2016 16:28:08:026 1      23        50
08/10/2016 16:28:09:026 1      12        45
08/10/2016 19:00:08:026 2      23        50
08/10/2016 20:28:08:026 1      23        50
08/10/2016 19:00:08:000 2      23        50
09/10/2016 01:02:33:123 2      23        50
09/10/2016 06:15:08:500 1      23        50
09/10/2016 10:01:07:022 3      28        88
```

Comment: Please take that data, copy it, and paste it into your question. Hope that isn't _too_ hard to do.

Comment: Hi COLDSPEED, Could you please help me about my question? I have edited. Actually I need No of Distinct Position for each user, each day.

Comment: You already accepted an answer... are you saying that didn't help?

Comment: It helped but I need that too. Because my teacher modified the question. I posted my new question as a new question

Comment: Sounds like you should do your own homework, dude!

Comment: Yep!! I know that.. But I don't know how to do group by two columns. I'm getting errors!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need:

First create datetime `Series` by [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) - `times` was removes, so get `datetime`s with no times. (thanks `cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ` for idea)

Then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) and get [`nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.nunique.html), last [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html):

```
days = pd.to_datetime(df['Time Stamp'].str.split().str[0])

s1 = df['Id'].groupby(days).nunique()
print (s1)
Time Stamp
2016-08-10    2
2016-09-10    3
Name: Id, dtype: int64


s1.plot()
```

For weeks convert to [`week`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.week.html)s:

```
weeks = days.dt.week

s2 = df['Id'].groupby(weeks).nunique()
print (s2)
Time Stamp
32    2
36    3
Name: Id, dtype: int64

s2.plot()
```

---

Another approach for all dates is [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html):

```
df['Days'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time Stamp'].str.split().str[0])

s2 = df.resample('D', on='Days')['Id'].nunique()
```

---

```
print (s2)
Days
2016-08-10    2
2016-08-11    0
2016-08-12    0
2016-08-13    0
2016-08-14    0
2016-08-15    0
2016-08-16    0
2016-08-17    0
2016-08-18    0
2016-08-19    0
2016-08-20    0
2016-08-21    0
2016-08-22    0
2016-08-23    0
2016-08-24    0
2016-08-25    0
2016-08-26    0
2016-08-27    0
2016-08-28    0
2016-08-29    0
2016-08-30    0
2016-08-31    0
2016-09-01    0
2016-09-02    0
2016-09-03    0
2016-09-04    0
2016-09-05    0
2016-09-06    0
2016-09-07    0
2016-09-08    0
2016-09-09    0
2016-09-10    3
Freq: D, Name: Id, dtype: int64
```

---

```
s2.plot()
```

For weeks:

```
s2 = df.resample('W', on='Days')['Id'].nunique()
print (s2)
Days
2016-08-14    2
2016-08-21    0
2016-08-28    0
2016-09-04    0
2016-09-11    3
Freq: W-SUN, Name: Id, dtype: int64


s2.plot()
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(df['Time stamp'])` doesn't work - see the format, it's weird.

Comment: Use `df['Time Stamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time Stamp'].str.split().str[0])` ... since you just need the week, you can get rid of the time.

Comment: First line is working. But second line said an error.                                
    df4(['Weeks']) = df4['Start_Time'].dt.week
                                              ^
   SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: Sorry, my typo. remove `()` like `df4['Weeks'] `

Comment: Thank you!! But actually I need distinct location visited (Latitude, Longitude) VS time.. not ID

Comment: If there are 2 columns, then it is more complicated. One solution is create tuples like `df['new'] = df[['Latitude','Longitude']].apply(tuple, axis=1)` and then instead `Id` use `new`. Because not so easy plot 2 columns together :(

Comment: Or `df['new'] = df['Latitude'].astype(str) + '_' + ,df['Longitude'].astype(str)`

Comment: The time stamp is not in as my original data.It should be within October 2016. Your days are August and September!!

Comment: So sorry, need `pd.to_datetime(df['Time Stamp'].str.split().str[0], dayfirst=True)`

Comment: I guess there is more dates like `20/10/2016 15:22:51:700`, then `dayfirst=True` is not necessary

Comment: Jezrael, if i say "number of  VISITED LOCATION VS time(per day or week) for EACH USER" how will be the code please? Thanks!

Comment: I think you need `days = pd.to_datetime(df['Time Stamp'].str.split().str[0])
df = df.groupby([days, 'Id','Latitude','Longitude'])` and then `['Id'].nunique().reset_index(name='count')`